# Installing a specific nginx-extras package on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, installation, apt-get

I am trying to install nginx-extras on Ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
```

It works fine, but it installs the latest version.  I need a very specific version, but none of my attempts to provide version are working.

Comment: By default ubuntu repos have only latest version of package. You'll have to find your specific version somewhere else. But I can't get *why* do you need a specific version?

Comment: The existing app works only with a specific version.

Comment: I don't believe there is something so specific in nginx. Actually I think you should solve the problem of your app to work with latest version of nginx.

Comment: To give a few more details, we are using Passenger + Nginx.  I agree that there should not be a dependency per say, but if there's a way to install specific version, it would be great.

Comment: You should mention it earlier. That's change everything.

Comment: BTW, version from passenger repo is latest (it uses `1:...` version name). Show result of `apt-cache policy nginx-extras` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install exact version (if it exists in your repos) with `package-name=VERSION` syntax.

E.g.:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-extras=1:1.10.0-8.5.0.28~wily1
```